# Executing Python with apache giving internal server error

Tags: python, apache2, cgi

I'm trying to execute python using Apache2. My apache2.conf file looks like this:

```
....
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/tcd/>
        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
....
```

The python file looks like this:

```
import cgi
cgi.test()
```

When I go to the URL that is suppose to execute the script I get the following:

[image]

I've followed multiple guides to try and get this to work but nothing seems to be working and it is not showing up in my log files. How can I get my apache server to execute Python efficiently?